# Word game: Where to get dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

For a game such as 'Words With Friends' http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/words-with-friends-free/id321916506?mt=8, how would you go about validating words?

Also, does GameCenter allow the social networking connections with other users?  Or does that have to be home rolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Moby Words](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mwords.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the iPhone but OS X, like most Unix flavors, has a word list at /usr/share/dict/words. You could check there.